# Microsoft Edge opens login.onmicrosoft.com in IE instead of visiting the page

Tags: internet-explorer, azure-active-directory, microsoft-edge

I have my app intergrated with AAD using Open ID Conect.

When I get following response from server, Microsoft EDGE open new IE window:

```
 Response Code: 302
 Location: https://login.microsoftonline.com/.....
```

I see also another request made by EDGE

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantid/oauth2/authorize?client_id=...&redirect_uri=...&response_type=id_token%20code&scope=openid%20profile&response_mode=form_post&nonce=...&state=...&x-client-SKU=ID_NETSTANDARD1_4&x-client-ver=5.2.0.0
```

Which is returning HTML with **X-UA-Compatible**

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

How do I modify my AAD OpenID Connect intergration so that I won't open IE?

Comment: it normally does that if it thinks the site is intranet see https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4019877/windows-10-open-internet-explorer-11-for-webpages-that-required-enterp

Comment: And that on the other hand is controlled by group policies when you are in corporate environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summ - up both the comments:

What you observe is not feature/option you can control over your OIDC implementation. This is feature of Edge browser, as [described here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4019877/windows-10-open-internet-explorer-11-for-webpages-that-required-enterp). In a corporate environment (domain joined PCs), your IT administrator control these settings over Group Policies. You have to talk to your it administrator to change this behavior for https://login.microsoftonline.com/. This is only way to change this behavior.

If you are not in a corporate environment - no domain join, no IT Admin, then check your local group policies as described in the article.